# Google App Script - Number Mismatched between filename and Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Everyone was so helpful on the last time I was stumped I thought I would come back.  I learned a lot from that last time and I have been successful on other projects since.

I am working on a script that will automatically generate an invoice in a Google Sheet, and then PDF it.  Everything is working as intended, with the exception if I remove line 23 of the below code the file name will say 'Invoice 2' but the invoice will read Invoice 1.  I only had that line there to try and trace the error, but it works as intended with it there; my question is why does it break if I remove line 23?

Thank you in advance!

```html
function autoInvoice() {
// Seting up to handle the spreadsheet
  var sheetID = 'ID'; //Edit this to your sheet ID.
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  let invoice = sheet.getSheetByName('Invoice');
  let dataValues = sheet.getSheetByName('Data').getDataRange().getValues(); // Gets all values of the sheet into an array
  let dataRowNum = sheet.getSheetByName('Data').getLastRow(); // Gets last row of the Autoforward Sheet
  let invoiceCell = invoice.getRange('C3');
  let clientCodeCell = invoice.getRange('C4');
  let invoiceDate = invoice.getRange('D5');
// A(0) - Active    Client - Yes / No
// B(1) - Client Code
// C(2) - Client Name
// D(3) - Owner Name
// E(4) - Owner E-Mail
// F(5) - Date of Invoice
  for (let a = 1; a < dataRowNum; a++) {
    let clientName = dataValues[a][2];
    if (dataValues[a][0] == 'Yes') {
      clientCodeCell.setValue(dataValues[a][1]); // Changes client code on invoice, sheet code does the rest
      let invoiceNum = parseInt(invoiceCell.getValue()) + 1; // Adds one to the invoice number
      invoiceCell.setValue(invoiceNum); // Sets the invoice number on the sheet
      Logger.log(invoiceNum + " " + invoiceCell.getValue());  // removing this causes the invoice in the file name to be mismatched to the invoice number
// Date Conversion
      var date = new Date(dataValues[a][5]); //convert js date into gs date
      dataValues[a][5] = Utilities.formatDate(date, "PDT", "yyyy-MM-dd"); //format date using gs method
      invoiceDate.setValue(dataValues[a][5]); // Sets date on Invoice
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
// Makes PDF
      const folderName = `Test Folder`;
      DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName)
        .next()
        .createFile(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
          .getBlob()
          .getAs(`application/pdf`)
          .setName(dataValues[a][5] + ' - ' + clientName + ' - Invoice #' + invoiceNum));  // Sets file name
      Logger.log(clientName + ' Active, making Invoice');
      Logger.log('Invoice #' + invoiceNum + ' created for ' + clientName);
    } else {
      Logger.log(clientName + " no longer active, skipping to next client")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Apps Script methods like getting and setting values can be asynchronous

- This is the reason why you implement `Utilities.sleep(1000);` to wait for the specified requests to finish before you proceed with further code execution.
- However, in you case the `sleep()` is apparently not enough. The `Logger.log` gives you additional waiting time for the right values to be fetched before continuing with code execution.
- I recommend you to implement before each line where a request is made that is dependant on values retrieved in a previous request a [Spreadsheet.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) call.
- As per documentation:

> Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance, such as when doing multiple calls to Range.getValue(). However, sometimes you may want to make sure that all pending changes are made right away, for instance to show users data as a script is executing.

- In other words, `Spreadsheet.flush()` will make sure that the name will not assigned to the pdf before the correct value for the given `for` loop iteration is retrieved.
- When making requests to the SpreadsheetApp, `Spreadsheet.flush()` is mostly preferable to `Utilities.sleep()` given that it forces the operaiton to become synchroneous and automatically adjusts the necessary amount of "sleeping time".

Comment: Wow, thank you.  This is great information to have!  I guess as my experience grows I need to review other functions that I didn't know exist, as I didn't even know that .flush() was a thing, but seeing it it becomes obvious this is exactly what is needed!